# How to always import a group of modules in Python

Tags: python, import

I use Python to do data analysis, and have a group of functions that I almost always use in my analysis. Is there any way to import the functions that I often use in one line or other easier way?

For example, when I start a new Jupyter Notebook for analysis, I put down a list of imports, such as

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...

from IPython.display import display, HTML, Markdown

Can I put those imports into a module and just do something like

import often_used_modules

And still be able to use those modules normally?

Comment: you could shorten your imports by writing it in a single line: `import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: @Leon Could you please share why you want to do that?

Comment: I would be concerned about subsequent side effects due to identically named functions.  As a rule, I try to import only the functions that are critical to the work I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do that

```py
# often_used_imports.py
import ...
...
```

and to use it:

```py
from often_used_imports import *
```

Comment: Just create a file containing all the necessary libraries and functions, then import *. So easy :)

Comment: Nice, it works!

Answer (score -1):

[image: This is] something you wanted to do but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind explaining why you wouldn't recommend it?

Comment: @Leon sure thing. Basically, if you would try to carry too much than you would need, would that be useful? No, right. It is the same thing actually. If you import any module that you would not use, then your program works slower than it should be. Maybe you are going to need only the train_test_split function from sklearn but if you do this way, then you'll import every single one of them.

Comment: @KannBerke. I see. Thanks for explaining this. Will be careful to only put the packages that I always need into "often_modules".